# Injecting an internal helper class while resolving a public class

Tags: architecture, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, autofac

I have the following architecture where a public Service class referencing an internal Helper class exists in another assembly:

```
ApplicationAssembly {
  public class Widget {
    public Widget(ReferencedAssembly.Service service) { ... }
  }
}

ReferencedAssembly {
  public class Service {
    public Service(Helper helper) { ... }
  }
  class Helper { ... }
}
```

(I realize that I can't put an internal class in the arguments of a public class's constructor--I'm just trying to illustrate the IoC pattern I'm going after.)

The problem is that `ApplicationAssembly` can't see `ReferencedAssembly.Helper`, so it can't be registered in my IoC container (Autofac in this case). As a result, `Helper` cannot be resolved when I try to resolve `Service`. What is my best option here?

- Option 1: Remove `Helper` from `Service`'s constructor and new it up in the constructor explicitly. I don't like this option because it kind of breaks the IoC paradigm.
- Option 2: Make `Helper` implement a public `IHelper` interface, then add a public module within `ReferencedAssembly` that registers `Helper` as an `IHelper`. I don't like this option because it requires `ApplicationAssembly` to know too many implementation details about `Service`, and if the user forgets to register that module at startup everything breaks.
- Option 3: Create a public static constructor on `Service` that builds a 2nd IoC container specifically for `ReferencedAssembly` and registers `Helper` in it. Remove `Helper` from `Service`'s constructor and resolve it within the constructor using the 2nd IoC container. This seems like my best option but requires more "plumbing" code than the others. I'm also not a big fan of public static constructors.
- Option 4. Change my architecture to something else altogether.

Comment: what about the simplest, and the best (Occam's razor) solution: just make the type public

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The way to register internal types with Autofac is to include an Autofac  [Module](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/StructuringWithModules) inside the assembly with the internal types, and register the module with the container. Because the module is in the same assembly it can configure the `ContainerBuilder` with the internal types.

I think the best option is to make `Service` implement a public interface, then make the `Service` class that you have currently internal. Autofac will happily instantiate an internal class to provide a public interface.

The other option (to allow `Service` to take a constructor dependency on an internal type) is to make `Service`'s constructor internal, and then use a constructor finder in the `Service` type registration:

```
builder.RegisterType<Service>()
  .FindConstructorsWith(new BindingFlagsConstructorFinder(BindingFlags.NonPublic));
```

Comment: It can't resolve BindingFlagsConstructorFinder in autofac 3.5. Would you know how to fix this?

Comment: For anyone who got here and hoped BindingFlagsConstructorFinder was an existing class, I pulled this from the DefaultConstructorFinder and modified it to find the internal constructors: `FindConstructorsWith(new InternalConstructorFinder);` where InternalConstructorFinder is: `public class InternalConstructorFinder : IConstructorFinder { public ConstructorInfo[] FindConstructors(Type t) 
 => t.GetTypeInfo().DeclaredConstructors.Where(c => !c.IsPrivate && !c.IsPublic).ToArray(); }`

Comment: `BindingFlagsConstructorFinder` was in Autofac 2.x (this answer is a bit outdated :-)) - you can see the original source [here](https://www.symbolsource.org/Public/Metadata/Default/Project/Autofac/2.2.4.900/Release/net-3.5/Autofac/Autofac/Core/Activators/Reflection/BindingFlagsConstructorFinder.cs?ImageName=Autofac).