# What is the proper way to inject internal class with embedded DI mechanism

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, .net-5

Can't find proper way to inject internal class from separate library. Found [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775323/injecting-an-internal-helper-class-while-resolving-a-public-class) for similar problem for Autofac, but can't find same one for embedded dependency injection mechanism.

My project structure looks like this:

Marketplace (asp.net) project:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMarketplaceDbContext();
    }
}
```

Business (library):

```cs
public static class DI
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddMarketplaceDbContext(
        this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSingleton<DeviceHandler>(x =>
        {
            var context = x.GetRequiredService<MarketplaceContext>();
            return new DeviceHandler(context);
        });
        return services.AddDbContext<MarketplaceContext>(options =>
            options.UseNpgsql("connection_string"));
    }
}

public class DeviceHandler
{
    private readonly MarketplaceContext _context;

    internal DeviceHandler(MarketplaceContext marketplaceContext)
    {
        _context = marketplaceContext;
    }
}

internal class MarketplaceContext : DbContext
{
    public MarketplaceContext(DbContextOptions<MarketplaceContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
}
```

And that works, but if I try to inject `DeviceHandler` like this

```cs
services.AddSingleton<MarketplaceHandler>();
```

Then I'm getting

> System.AggregateException: 'Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Business.Core.DeviceHandler Lifetime: Singleton ImplementationType: Business.Core.DeviceHandler': A suitable constructor for type 'Business.Core.DeviceHandler' could not be located. Ensure the type is concrete and services are registered for all parameters of a public constructor.)'
>
> 1 of 2 Inner Exceptions:
>
> InvalidOperationException: Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Business.Core.DeviceHandler Lifetime: Singleton ImplementationType: Business.Core.DeviceHandler': A suitable constructor for type 'Business.Core.DeviceHandler' could not be located. Ensure the type is concrete and services are registered for all parameters of a public constructor.
>
> 2 of 2 Inner Exceptions:
>
> InvalidOperationException: A suitable constructor for type 'Business.Core.DeviceHandler' could not be located. Ensure the type is concrete and services are registered for all parameters of a public constructor.

Hope that anybody knows better (or proper) solution.

Comment: I think issue can be related to fact that `DeviceHandler` is registered as singleton and default lifetime for `AddDbContext` is `Scoped`, and you can't use scoped services in singletons, only other singleton and transient ones.

Comment: Tried both `Scoped` and `Transient` - doesn't help.

Comment: Note that `MarketplaceContext` became a [Captive Dependency](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/02/captive-dependency/) because you registered `DeviceHandler` as Singleton.